# Speaker on when headset plugged in

Tags: iphone, headphones

I would like to keep my headset plugged into my iPhone 5S but have the ringer audible from the phone when I don't have the earbuds in my ears.  is this possible?   I don't like to have to hurry up and plug in my headset when a call comes in and I sometimes miss calls when it is plugged in and I don't have the earbuds in my ears.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed it is possible. Turn off the silent mode of your iPhone (toggle on the left) then set your ringtone to be audible and voilà! Your iPhone will ring even with the earphones plugged in.